# mysql query with enums

Tags: mysql

I have the following 3 rows in my database table

```
ID      resID   userID  source  event   pos     award 
3239    23796   8365    18      120     0       qualified        
3670    23796   8365    18      120     1       Finalist         
3671    23796   8365    18      120     0       first
```

Now the award column is enum ( "first","Finalist","qualified" ) 
I need to get the best of the award from the 3 rows i.e

```
ID      resID   userID  source  event   pos     award 
3671    23796    8365     18     120     0      first
```

I tried the following query

```
SELECT * from sometable 
WHERE userID = 8365 
GROUP BY userID
having min(award+0)
```

But it is not working . Could some one give some pointers

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand your query - min(type + 0) doesn't appear to refer to a column in your table...

Comment: type+0 is used to get the integer value of a enum in mysql

Comment: sorry it is award+0 . Edited the question

Comment: Perhaps you want the simple `SELECT * from sometable WHERE userID = 8365 AND award = 'first'`

Comment: @ypercube I think not all rows have award='first'.

Comment: @Karolis: Ah, I see now what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM sometable 
WHERE userID = 8365
ORDER BY award
LIMIT 1;
```

Another way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sometable s
WHERE 
    userID = 8365 AND
    award = (
        SELECT MIN(award) 
        FROM sometable 
        WHERE userID = s.userID
    )
```

Comment: anyway we could avoid limit ?

Comment: @Karolis; can you explain the difference between `ORDER BY award+0` and `ORDER BY award`  ?

Comment: @ypercube In theory `+0` converts enum value into index. But accordint to what I see now, MySQL works with indexes by default, so `+0` is not needed. Updating my answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from sometable WHERE userID = 8365
    ORDER BY FIELD( award, 'first', 'Finalist', 'qualified' ) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: anyway we could avoid limit ?

Comment: @rrmo Why do you want to avoid LIMIT?

Comment: because i want the best award out of the 3 rows . Here i just gave an example .But for me i would get tons of rows . so for me limit would not work .

Comment: @rrmo Using `LIMIT 1` is the conventional way of doing such queries and MySql is optimized to deal with that, it will quit searching and returns the results as soon as it finds the top row.

Comment: @nobody This is true only if index can be used for sorting.